# Android L - Activity with Fragment display error (only the fragment is displayed)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

As the title says, when I try to make a simple activity with a fragment, all I get on screen is the fragment content. The status bar, the background, everything is missing. [I made a video to show what happens [0:47]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9v7KV7y-SU). If you watch the video, the app works on KitKat, but fails on Lollipop. I'm not sure if this is a L Preview failure.

The code for my `MainActivity` is generated by Android Studio:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle prevState)
    {
        super.onCreate(prevState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(prevState == null)
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if(id == R.id.action_settings)
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {

        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle prevState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

My `.xml` file is just a `FrameLayout` with a `fragment` element inside of it. It's replaced in the `onCreate(Bundle prevState)` method as shown above.

Here's my `MainActivity` XML file:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="me.kworden.dart.fragment.MainFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My styles look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#C40048</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FF005D</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#AEFF00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You're supplying the ID of the fragment to the `FragmentTransaction#replace` call.  It should be the ID of the container `R.id.main_container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to remove the fragment and then add the new one to see if that fails. 
I would also try to do the replace a bit later after onCreate.

Btw, why do you still use L preview, and not L ?

Also, it's not super clear to me if the id can be the id of the fragment itself. The docs seem to refer to a container Id more than to a fragment id...

Comment: I'll give this a try when I have access to my computer, thanks

Comment: Switched to L Release and everything worked after using `main_container` instead of `main_fragment`